# How to ignore .npmrc config locally

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, npmrc

I've added `.npmrc` file to the root of my project with next content:

```
arch=x64
platform=linux
```

This helps GitLab CI to build `node_modules` of my app for AWS Lambda for right architecture and platform.

But this broke my local development. `yarn install` installs dependencies for x64 linux, but I am on ARM MacBook.

How can I fix it?